# What are the tasks performed by "npm start" command in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

Please help with my below questions:

1. "**npm**" is the one which comes when we install **Node.js**. Am I correct?
2. "**create-react-app**" package installs/loads the **Babel** & **Webpack** which are required for our React project. Am I correct?
3. When will the React code gets compiled & Translated? Does the below points are correct?

a. After creating React project and developing some code, we are loading our application in browser by running the "**npm start**" command. So while running this command, will the Babel is going to compile the React code and convert it to JavaScript code which has ES5 standards? Does this conversion to ES5 happens when we run the "npm start" command?

b. Also I learned that **Webpack** is going to merge all various files within the React project to a single **.js** file. So does this merging of all the different files by Webpack will be performed when we run "**npm start**" command?

4. So if my above understanding is correct, the React code will be **Compiled, Translated & Merged** into a single file when we run "**npm start**" command. Correct?

Comment: You can look exactly what npm start does here: 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm start` is really just a command that exists in the `package.json` which can be configured to do whatever you please. It is typically use to kick off all things needed to "start" the app. In the context of a react app created using `create-react-app` the `start` command will call `react-scripts start` and that points to a file called `react-scripts` which sits in your `node_modules/.bin`. If you want to see everything that happens you can read through that file.

In short tho, you are correct that it will use babel to transpile the code to something the browser understands, it will use webpoack to create one bundle file (or multiple if you are using code splitting). It will also start a webpack dev server which will usually listen on port 3000 and it will open your default browser to your app. These default settings can be overwritten in the `package.json`.

Hope this gives you some clarity.